# How do I modify the "view" link in a view?

Tags: 7, views

I'm sure this is a simple question when you know what you're doing, but I'm a bit puzzled.

At the moment, I have a view, from the views module, listing published articles on the front page of my site. After each article, there is a link "view" or "voir" (depending on the language being used) which takes you to the article. This is simply an anchor tag generated by thte Views module containing a link to the article node appended to the end of the item.

However, the person for whom I am making the site wants this link to be styled in a specific way, with an icon and the text to read "Read more" or "Savoir plus". How or where can I modify the HTML markup and text content for this particular element of the View module output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 'Add fields' on your View, you can select 'Content: Link', which generates a simple link to your content. When configuring this 'field' you can set the 'Text to display' property and under 'Style settings' specify any CSS classes you want (see screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Thank you @MrWatergate, can you advise on my second problem, how to make the "Text to Display" field respond to the language setting, so it will say "Read more" when the internationalisation option is set to English?

Comment: For multilingual Views, I'm using the Internatiolization (https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) and Internationalization Views (https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) modules.